# What is equivalent for Codeception waitForElement method?

Tags: testing, codeception, end-to-end, cypress

[Codeception::waitForElement](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#waitForElement)

I'm rewriting some tests from PHP based testing framework. I've a problem to detect new DOM elements fetched by Ajax POST request.

When I use:

```
cy.wait(timeout);
```

I'm able to fill text input loaded upon Ajax request, but this is an anti pattern.

I've also tried solution from: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/937#issuecomment-345786498 - not working in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a `cy.get()` to wait for certain `DOM` elements to be rendered. Cypress will retry until the `timeout` is up:

```
cy.get('.request-button').click()
cy.get('.some-new-element', {timeout: 10000})
// Cypress waits up to 10 seconds for element to appear
cy.get('.new-button').click()
// continue with test knowing the DOM has
```

...

#### **What if the new elements don't have a unique selector?**

Well then you've got a bigger problem, since you'll need to use selectors to perform actions on elements anyways.

In this case, you can assert on text if it's nested anywhere inside an element using `cy.contains()`:

```
cy.contains('.common-class', 'new text', {timeout:10000})
```

You **cannot do this**:

```
cy.get('.common-class).contains('new text')
```

Because Cypress will not query the `DOM` again after a successful `cy.get()`, only watch the **already found `.common-class`** `DOM node` for changes.

Comment: That is pretty obvious actually. I keep forgetting about timeout options.

Comment: @bkucera thanks for the answer. What if similar selector is already in page content. I'm dealing with Ajax content with a class instead of id: .ajax-new-content ... :/

Comment: If there is no way to distinguish by selector, and you want to wait for say 3 elements of class `myClass`, then I am guessing you can shift the timeout to the `eq()` command like so: `cy.get('.myClass').eq(2,  {timeout: 3000})`.

Comment: @RichardMatsen actually...that will not work because Cypress will not retry the DOM query if it already succeeds...so Cypress will find `.myclass` and not ever go back to find the new one. This allows you to keep reference to an element after it might lose reference in the DOM

Comment: @drupality see my updated answer for non-unique selectors

Comment: @bkucera - indeed, Cypress does not retry the `cy.get()` when chaining `.eq(2)` or even `.should('contain', 'new text')`

Comment: @bkucera thanks, but in my case text is identical to previous loaded piece of content ... only underneath markup is diffenent, seems like I have to forgot about having reusable command with those tests

Comment: @drupality what do you mean by underneath content?

Comment: @bkucera, sorry wrong word, I've meant markup, id/name attributes

Comment: @drupality well that's all you need! 
`cy.get('#myid')` or `cy.get('.my class[name="myname"]')`